# how to merge two array of objects into single array and object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I would like to know how to merge two array of objects into single array using javascript

```
var arr1 = [
  {id:1, name: "xxx"}
]

var arr2 =[
 {details:"finance", cost:"100"}
]

Tried.
var result1 = [...arr1, ...arr2];
var result=Object.assign({}, ...result1)
```

Expected Output
[
{
id:1,
name: "xxx",
details:"finance",
cost:"100"
}
]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr1 = [
  {id:1, name: "xxx"}
]

var arr2 =[
 {details:"finance", cost:"100"}
]

const result = arr1.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, ...arr2[index] }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inner-wrap you `[...arr1, ...arr2]` in curly braces and access via array index: `[{...arr1[0], ...arr2[0]}]`

```js
var arr1 = [
  {id:1, name: "xxx"}
]

var arr2 =[
 {details:"finance", cost:"100"}
]

var result1 = [{...arr1[0], ...arr2[0]}];

console.log(result1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also concat both arrays and then reduce the whole array to assign to a new object:

```js
var arr1 = [
  {id:1, name: "xxx"}
]

var arr2 =[
 {details:"finance", cost:"100"}
]

const result = arr1.concat(arr2).reduce(((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c)), {});
console.log(result)
```

I prefer this because you can add as many arrays as you want to the concat function.